# does Apache Ignite replicated cache supports both SYNC and ASYNC?

Tags: ignite

does FULL_ASYNC, FULL_SYNC and PRIMARY_SYNC from CacheWriteSynchronizationMode apply to replicated mode?
https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.html

I ask this because a course on pluralsight (Getting Started with Apache Ignite 2) says it only applies to partitioned mode.
But the ignite doc does not mention this, it even says about PRIMARY_SYNC (which is ASYNC between nodes):

> "This flag only makes sense for CacheMode.PARTITIONED and
> CacheMode.REPLICATED modes."

SO it sounds like it applies to both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it applies to both.

The `REPLICATED` cache, similar to the `PARTITIONED` one, has primary and backup partitions, which will be updated corresponding to the configured write synchronization mode.

You can find more details regarding that [here](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-modeling/data-partitioning#replicated) and [here](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/configuring-backups#synchronous-and-asynchronous-backups).